# Pull images from private registry with self sign certificates Kubernetes containerd

Tags: kubernetes, kubeconfig

I know there are many questions about this and also many answers about how to configure containerd to allow insecure and so on ...

What I do have is a kubeconfig file with admin access to the Kubernetes cluster.
What I do not want is to touch are Kubernetes nodes.

Is it there a way to allow the certificate into Kubernetes cluster w/o touching the nodes or to allow pulling images from non tls registries [ I don't need necessary to have tls registries, I just need to be able to pull image from it tls/nontls will work fine for my needs]

Regards,

LE: Something that I'm trying and still not working. If I'll add the CA certificate to /etc/ssl/certs and update certs pulling images will work. But if I'll create a new private registry and trying to pull images from it it will not work (after I'll put its CA certificate into /etc/ssl/certs and update certs)
any reason ?
error:

```
 x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error ..."
```